# Neo4j StartService Failed 1053

Tags: neo4j

recentely I met a problem about Neo4j.
As I start Neo4j Server,it was installed successfully,but when i start the service,error comes,it reports:
[SC]StartService FAILED:1053
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Then I use :  Neo4j.bat console ,it works well,but i still can't access  localhost:7474

my dev env is： Neo4j-community-1.9.M01 and the os is Win7 64bit

Anyone knows the reason?
Many Thanks

Comment: was this resolved on the google group?

Answer (score 2):

Fire up powershell and head to the /bin directory in your Neo4j bundle. Run the following command:

PS ..\neo4j-community-1.9.M03\bin> ./Neo4j.bat console

If you get an error that says something like, "Unable to access jarfile C:\PROGRA~1\NEO4J-~1.1\bin\windows-service-wrapper-*.jar," then a quick fix is to open /bin/base.bat with any text editor (probably notepad) and then change this line:

set wrapperJarFilename=windows-service-wrapper-*.jar

to this line:

set wrapperJarFilename=windows-service-wrapper-4.jar

I'm not sure why the wildcard isn't working, but this allowed me to install Neo4j. I found the solution here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/391

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been an issue since (at least) 1.7. I've no idea why this fix isn't better publicised, except possibly that Windows is not their target OS (I don't have this issue running Neo4j on ubuntu)

Comment: Yeah, you're absolute right -- this error isn't present if you run it on the Java 1.6 platform.

Comment: Thanks Brent, that helps a little.  It at least lets 'us' run the console.  The NeoJ system service doesn't start even with that change.

Comment: The wildcard shouldn't work because it is not a legal Windows file name.  Perhaps the Java 1.6 loader did a file expansion and 1.7 loaded the literal string.  The Windows shell is not responsible for expanding wildcards like on *NIX.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - I started Neo4j Server,it was installed successfully,but later on as I tried to start, it reported... : [SC]StartService FAILED:1053 The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
I found that under "\neo4j-community-1.9.2\data\graph.db" the file "tm_tx_log.1" was not deleted. I deleted the file & it started fine with bin>Neo4j.bat start